# String is truncated at NUL-character when passing data to @JavascriptInterface method

Tags: java, android, string, null-terminated

I'm interfacing a webview with javascript through this function to save data into a file

```
@JavascriptInterface
public Boolean saveToFile(String filename, String text) {
    try{
      File file = new File(filename);
      byte[] b = text.getBytes();
      FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
      fileOutputStream.write(b);
      fileOutputStream.close();  
      return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
      return false;
    }
}
```

At javascript side I have this:

```
function save(filename, text) {
  return Android.saveToFile(filename, text);
}
```

When I save ascii text, it's ok, but whenever I send binary data, if "text" contains a null character (\0), the Android function truncates the received argument "text" at that null character like it was receiving a null terminated string, which is not the case, nor with java nor javascript.

Any one has an idea about how to solve it?

Comment: I guess it it's an Android bug and I created an issue, let's see if someone there could help us to solve this problem... [issue 69542](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69542)

Comment: ok, I removed mine too, I'm already using base64 and there is another issue with unicode chars too, I'll wait for this bug report and then I'll publish results here. I deleted my comments too, when you read this one, I'll delete it too. See you!